# How to clear timeout in javascript?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

Why is this not working?

```
    $('#plugbot-likebox').hover(function () {

      $('#plugbot-ui').slideDown();
      $('#ZobrazNastavenia').fadeOut("fast");

    }, function () {
              toUi = setTimeout(function(){
              $('#plugbot-ui').slideUp();
              }, 1500);

            toNastavenia = setTimeout(function(){
                $('#ZobrazNastavenia').fadeIn("fast");
            }, 2000);

    });
```

I need clear timeout but this not working. Please tell me why. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`timeoutUI`  and `timeoutNastavenia` are variables that are locally scoped to the anonymous functions you define them in.

If you want them available in a wider scope, then you have to declare them in a wider scope.

Don't use `var` inside the anonymous functions. Do use `var variableName` outside of those functions. (e.g. just before the first line of the code in the question).

Comment: becuause i cant edit more code.. here is screenshot http://www.myscreen.cz/img/d461a16202a6fa4c4807e3f4ad56ff273a4694cf

Comment: `timeoutUI` and `timeoutNastavenia` are not local either, both are missing the `var` keyword, they are thus implied globals.

Comment: @papirtiger — This answer refers to [the code before the OP severely edited it](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21553547/3).

Comment: now I have `var toUI = setTimeout`.. and `var toNastavenia = setTimeout`... and still not working

Answer (score 0):

this is an example to clear timeout:

```
var myVar;

function myFunction()
{
myVar = setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
}

function myStopFunction()
{
clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

as you can see myVar is defined in global scope, so in your code it will not work because timeoutUI and timeoutNastavenia are private variables, you should use `timeoutUI=...` instead of `var timeoutUI=..`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm using jQuery and timeouts, then I always set them on the element itself:

```
$('#plugbot-ui').data(
    'timeout-toUi',
    setTimeout(function(){
          $('#plugbot-ui').slideUp();
    }, 1500)
);
```

This way you can clear the timeout by getting the ID off of the element itself:

```
clearTimeout($('#plugbot-ui').data('timeout-toUi'));
```

By the way, when using jQuery you can just use `.delay()`:

```
$('#plugbot-ui').delay(1500).slideUp();
```

And you can use `.stop()` to stop the animation and clear and finish all animations:

```
$('#plugbot-ui').stop(true, true);
```